# learnr application doesn' work on shiny server

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I'm a beginer with shiny server. I've installed it on my computer and I get the default app working correctly on http://localhost:3838/sample-apps/rmd/.

However, I've tried some learnr apps (that I copied in the /srv/shiny-server/sample-apps/rmd/ directory) which all failed with the message :
"An error has occured. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification"

The log file on /var/log/shiny-server says (as far as I understand it) that the learnr package is not installed, although it actually is and the learnr apps works perfectly on my computer while launched from RStudio.

--

```
Warning: Error in : package or namespace load failed for 'learnr':
    .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'learnr', details:
    call: NULL
    error: The shiny_prerendered_chunk function can only be called from within runtime: shiny_prerendered
    139: stop
    138: value[[3L]]
    137: tryCatchOne
    136: tryCatchList
    135: tryCatch
    134: library
    133: eval
    132: eval
    127: evaluate_call
    126: evaluate::evaluate
    125: evaluate
    123: block_exec
    122: call_block
    121: process_group.block
    118: process_file
    117: knitr::knit
    116: <Anonymous>
    111: <reactive>
    95: doc
    94: shiny::renderUI
    93: func
    80: origRenderFunc
    79: output$__reactivedoc__
    3: <Anonymous>
    1: rmarkdown::run
```

Comment: The error of package have not installed is not like this as far as I know.....
How did you install your "learnr" package, you install through Rstudio or command in terminal?

Comment: First through Rstudio, and then I tried also the command line :

Comment: sudo su - -c "R -e \"install.packages('learnr')\"" the library is on /usr/local/lib/R/site-library

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. In fact, the issue is not that you did not install learnr properly; your issue is actually a namespace issue. It can be solved by installing the tidyverse package with install.packages("tidyverse") directly on your server machine.

Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message. However, I tried to deploy `exercise.Rmd` on an Ubuntu machine (18.04 x64) running the latest versions of R, RStudio server and ShinyServer. The deployment folder, which caused the error was sub-folder `da` of `/opt/shiny-server/samples/sample-apps/`. That means, `http://r.smartana.org/sample-apps/da/exercise.Rmd` showed an error.

My **solution** was to create a folder having the same file-name as the folder-name and add the corresponding html file. That means, in the `sample-apps` folder I added `exercise/exercise.Rmd` and `exercise/exercise.html`. Now this can be accessed via  `http://r.smartana.org/sample-apps/exercise/` and  `http://r.smartana.org/sample-apps/exercise/exercise.Rmd` (but not via the html extension).

**Lessons learned**:

1. deployment file-name and its folder-name must be identical;
2. corresponding html-file is required.